# Why is MD RAID 0 slower then either backing drive alon

Tags: raid, mdadm, nvme

I created a MD RAID 0 array using two NVME drives. I realize using two different drives, rather than identical drives is not optimal, but when I just bought the new one they are all faster than my 1 year old drive. 
Using Patriot Scorch 512GB Nvme and Mushkin Helix 256GB. I made a 32GB partition on each, and created the MD RAID 0 array using 16k chunks, then formated to EXT4 to test.

```
kde-swiebel@T5600-kde:~$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid0] 
unused devices: <none>
kde-swiebel@T5600-kde:~$ sudo mdadm -Cv -l0 -c16 -n2 /dev/md0   /dev/nvme0n1p3 /dev/nvme1n1p2 
mdadm: /dev/nvme0n1p3 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
       size=34277376K  mtime=Wed Dec 31 17:00:00 1969
mdadm: /dev/nvme1n1p2 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
       size=34277376K  mtime=Wed Dec 31 17:00:00 1969
Continue creating array? y
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
kde-swiebel@T5600-kde:~$ cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid0] 
md0 : active raid0 nvme1n1p2[1] nvme0n1p3[0]
      68487168 blocks super 1.2 16k chunks

unused devices: <none>
kde-swiebel@T5600-kde:~$ sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/md0
mke2fs 1.44.6 (5-Mar-2019)
Discarding device blocks: done                            
Creating filesystem with 17121792 4k blocks and 4284416 inodes
Filesystem UUID: f9826f0f-7ba4-40b2-9c9f-861379e82703
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (131072 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

Benchmarks from Gnome-disk-utility 3.32.1

```
1000 samples, 1MB size

Patriot Scorch
average read: 1362.2 MB/s
Average write: 228.7 MB/s
Average access time 0.07 msec

Mushkin Helix
Average read: 1529.5 MB/s
Average write: 1003.1 MB/s
Average access time 0.06 msec

/dev/md0 
Average read: 1751.3 MB/s
Average write: 26.9 MB/s
Average access time 0.05 msec
```

Change to 100 samples, 100MB size, read-only

```
/dev/md0 
Average read: 2927.6 MB/s
Average write: NA
Average access time 0.04 msec
```

The read speed, while it is faster than either drive alone, is not too impressive but when I changed the test to read-only, it greatly improved. 
The write speed, however, was horrible. Write speed was 10% of the slowest drive.

I tried removing the RAID array and creating it with different chunk sizes (4K, 32K, 128K) but little changed with each. Write speed was between 11MB/s to 32MB/s

According to [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=samsung-960-raid&num=1) and [other sites](https://www.overclock.net/forum/320-raid-controllers-software/1535527-ssd-raid-0-stripe-size-differences-benchmarks-raid-0-mixing-different-drives-vs-same-drive-benchmarks.html) I'm doing this right and should see much more gain.

Using mdadm version 4.1-1ubuntu1, kernel 5.0.0-25-generic
Running on a Dell T5600 with dual Xeon E5-2609(Quad core 2.4Ghz)

Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Update: Raffa pointed out not to fully trust benchmarks. I performed some file transfer tests, both with a large 4.6GB file and hundreds of small files, and the transfer speed was better than the benchmark speed of 30MB per second, but still slower than either of the two drives alone.

For this test, I transferred a 4.6GB file. I ran each test four times, taking the average of the four transfer times to calculate the speed in MB per second. I allowed the drives to cool for one minute between each test. There were some instances of throttling, which were much longer times, and I threw out those times, waited and performed the individual test again. The Mushkin gets even slower when throttled, around 30MB/s.

```
From    To  MB/s
RamDisk RamDisk 1766
Mushkin RamDisk 1076
Patriot RamDisk 964
Raid    RamDisk 746
RamDisk Patriot 572
Mushkin Patriot 556
RamDisk Raid    347
Patriot Raid    321
Raid    Patriot 308
Patriot Patriot 292
RamDisk Mushkin 203
Mushkin Raid    185
Raid    Raid    181
Patriot Mushkin 179
Raid    Mushkin 164
Mushkin Mushkin 128
```

Copying to the RamDisk is of course fastest. Of note, reading from the Raid was slower than either of the two drives backing the Raid. Looks like the Mushkin write performance is just garbage. 
I'm guessing that there's something weird with the timing between the two drives that is causing md raid to have issues. But with the slow write performance of the Mushkin, there's little reason for me to keep it.

The Patriot is on sale for $25, which makes it, a good deal even though it's an older model. Should I get that? Would having two of the same model drive help with read/write speed.

Comment: SSDs with or without RAID 0. I doubt if there is any noticeable performance gain on most systems. These are fast enough by nature and way beyond any raid configuration and can even be multiple times faster than RAID cards themselves. If you however insist on trying, I would update the system BIOS and the SSD firmware first. Please have a look and compare your BIOS version https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=27w1p and your SSD sfirmware versions  https://www.info.patriotmemory.com/scorch-m-2-ssd

Comment: Be very careful though. Especially with the BIOS update. Also please do not base your decision entirely on the benchmarks, they do not usually reflect on real life read and write speeds. Try copying from and to a ram disk instead.